# Javascript high score update regardless of whether new score is higher or not

Tags: javascript, function

Newbie here! Apologies if I have not formatted this correctly.
I have a whack-a-mole game and want to keep score in local storage. The function at the bottom called 'highscore' is not working - it updates the 'highscore' regardless of whether it is in fact higher than the previous score or not!
I'm sure I'm missing something super obvious, like I say, very new to this! Only using Vanilla Javascript at this stage so hints or solutions in keeping would be ideal.
Any help or pointers in the right direction much appreciated!
Thank you!

```
  window.onload = function() {
    setUp();
    count = 0;
    myDiv = document.getElementById("mole");
    myDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {});
  };

  function setUp() {
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "mole.png";
    img.onclick = function(event) {
      whackedMole();
    };
    img.className = "mole";
    img.id = "mole";
    document.getElementById("moleMap")
      .rows[randomNumber()].cells[randomNumber()].appendChild(img);
  }


  function randomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  }


  function whackedMole() {
    let mole = document.getElementById("mole");
    let audio = new Audio('whack-audio.wav');
    audio.play();
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = (++count);
    mole.parentNode.removeChild(mole);
    setUp();
  }



  let myTimer = 0;

  function clock() {
    myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
    var c = 10;

    function myClock() {
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = --c;
      if (c <= 0) {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
        alert("Your score is " + count + "!");
        highscore();
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = 0;
        count = 0;
      }
    }
  }


//This is the function in question;

  function highscore() {
    document.getElementById("highscore").innerHTML = count;
    let highscore = count;
    if (count <= highscore) {
      return;
    } else if (count > highscore) {
      localStorage.setItem('highscore', count);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `count <= highscore` will be always true because `count` and `highscore` both are equal

Comment: Sorry but this confuses me. You set highscore to count and then expect it to be different? I don't understand how you are even changing the score as you should always get the return and not the setItem

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly the problem lies in this code:

```
function highscore() {
    document.getElementById("highscore").innerHTML = count;
    let highscore = count;
    if (count <= highscore) {
        return;
    } else if (count > highscore) {
        localStorage.setItem('highscore', count);
    }
}
```

and specifically on these two lines:

```
document.getElementById("highscore").innerHTML = count;
```

and

```
let highscore = count;
```

Everytime you call highscore(); you are updating your DOM regardless of if the count is > than the highscore. Then on the second line of code that i have hinted highscore gets the value of count so the first statement in the if clause will always evaluate to true. What i would do is modify the code as following:

```
function highscore() {
    // Just in case the highscore is not yet initialized.
    if (!localstorage.getItem('highscore')) {
        localstorage.setItem('highscore', count);
    }
    let highscore = localstorage.getItem('highscore');
    if (count <= highscore) {
        return;
    } else if (count > highscore) {
        document.getElementById("highscore").innerHTML = count;
        localStorage.setItem('highscore', count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a very helpful answer to a newbie!